# Game Center - Matchmaking based on skill - playerGroup - range

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, matchmaking

Is it possible to do matchmaking based on a range of player skill?

Let's imagine in a game there's player skill ranks from 1-10 and I'd like to match players with their own rank and players +/- 2 ranks.

How would one do this with Game Center Matchmaking? (**GKMatchRequest**)

GKMatchRequest has the playerGroup property, but it's only a single number. Hence I could only realize matchmaking based on single number instead of a range. Is there anyway to achieve matchmaking based on a skill range?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to this as of now. I guess you can request the functionality via the Apple bug reporter. It must be a common use case.

In the meantime maybe you can do with something like this (if it's ok with Apple):

1. Try to find a match within own rank. Timeout if not successful, and abort the match.
2. Try to find a match within own rank + 1. Timeout if not successful, and abort the match.
3. Try to find a match within own rank - 1. Timeout if not successful, and abort the match.
4. Try to find a match within own rank with no timeout.